# Rails Validation Failing for Create Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

So I'm trying to get my new/create actions working with form_for for my resource 'project' but the create form in 'new.html.erb' seems to think that the parameter 'version' is blank when I submit it, even though I am setting it equal to 1.

**Projects Controller**

```
def new
  @project = current_user.projects.build if user_signed_in?
  @project.version = 1
  @project.unique_id = rand(1000000)
  while(Project.find_by_unique_id(@project.unique_id) != nil)
    @project.unique_id = rand(1000000)
  end
end

def create
  @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project created!"
    redirect_to user_url(current_user.username)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:description, :name, :media, :content_type, :file_size, :unique_id, :verison)
end
```

end

**New.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for(@project, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, maxlength: 50, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "What is it all about?", class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.file_field :media, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,audio/mpeg,audio/vnd.wave' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :version %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :unique_id %>  

  <%= f.submit "Create Project", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Project Model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :unique_id, presence: true
  validates :version, presence: true
end
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You might be strong_params filtering out your version parameter.  Can you show us the `project_params` function in your Projects controller?

Comment: Hmmm. I added them in!

Comment: oh wow. I just noticed a typo in the strong params... That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to JTG. There appeared to be a typo in my strong params which was causing 'version' to be filtered out and thus not passed through.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I would set it equal to one in the form as a hidden field like this:

```
<div>
   <%= f.hidden_field :version, value: 1  class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
```

I would also get rid of @project.version = 1 in your project new action.

Comment: Why isn't it passing '1' through without being explicit though? My other hidden field 'unique_id' seems to work fine.